# authenticating into Google Play Game Services on android results in error when signing in with Google Apps account

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

While authenticating into Google+ I experienced an "unknown error" message when signing in with a google apps account.

I have multiple accounts, one personal gmail and another is a google apps account.

When signing in via the personal gmail account, all is well. 
Signing in with a google apps email address (the same I have registered to the developer console and google play services and google APIs) there is an error.

Below is the logcat output. Any ideas what's happening?

```
D/Prime31 (26004): beginUserInitiatedSignIn: starting new sign-in flow.D/Prime31 (26004): Connecting GamesClient.

E/GmsClient(26004): Calling connect() while still connected, missing disconnect().

D/Prime31 (26004): onConnectionFailed: result 4

D/Prime31 (26004): onConnectionFailed: since user initiated sign-in, trying to resolve problem.

D/Prime31 (26004): resolveConnectionResult: trying to resolve result: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{422add70: android.os.BinderProxy@422c87c0}}

D/Prime31 (26004): --------------------- result has resolution. Starting it. --------------------

I/Prime31-Proxy(26004): showing the login UI

I/ActivityManager(  506): START u0 {cmp=com.google.android.gms/.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity (has extras)} from pid -1

D/overlay (  159): Set pipe=RGB1 dpy=0;

I/ActivityManager(  506): START u0 {act=com.google.android.gms.common.account.CHOOSE_ACCOUNT flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.account.AccountPickerActivity (has extras)} from pid 1244

I/ActivityManager(  506): Displayed com.phyken.wizardopstactics/com.prime31.PlayServicesProxyActivity: +763ms

I/ActivityManager(  506): Displayed com.google.android.gms/.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity: +188ms

I/ActivityManager(  506): Displayed com.google.android.gms/.common.account.AccountPickerActivity: +94ms

D/overlay (  159): Set pipe=VG0 dpy=0; Set pipe=VG1 dpy=0;

D/overlay (  159): Unset pipe=VG0 dpy=0; Unset pipe=VG1 dpy=0; Unset pipe=RGB1 dpy=0;

D/alsa_ucm(  162): snd_use_case_set(): uc_mgr 0x417b5d58 identifier _verb value Inactive

D/alsa_ucm(  162): Set mixer controls for HiFi Lowlatency enable 0

D/alsa_ucm(  162): snd_use_case_set(): uc_mgr 0x417b5d58 identifier _disdev value DMIC Endfire TMUS

D/alsa_ucm(  162): disdev: device DMIC Endfire TMUS not enabled, no need to disable

D/alsa_ucm(  162): snd_use_case_set(): uc_mgr 0x417b5d58 identifier _disdev value Speaker

D/alsa_ucm(  162): Set mixer controls for Speaker enable 0

I/ActivityManager(  506): Start proc com.google.android.apps.maps:GoogleLocationService for service com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.location.internal.server.GoogleLocationService: pid=2063 uid=10039 gids={50039, 3003, 1015, 1028}

D/dalvikvm( 2063): GC_CONCURRENT freed 206K, 3% free 8925K/9164K, paused 5ms+1ms, total 37ms

D/dalvikvm( 2063): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 23ms

D/dalvikvm( 2063): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 125K, 4% free 9016K/9388K, paused 11ms, total 11ms

I/dalvikvm-heap( 2063): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.006MB for 186718-byte allocation

D/dalvikvm( 2063): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 9198K/9572K, paused 13ms, total 13ms

D/dalvikvm( 2063): GC_CONCURRENT freed 471K, 6% free 9114K/9616K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 17ms

D/dalvikvm( 2063): GC_CONCURRENT freed 131K, 2% free 9481K/9644K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 23ms

W/ActivityManager(  506): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10023

W/BroadcastQueue(  506): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=com.google.android.location.internal.server.ACTION_RESTARTED flg=0x10 } from com.google.android.apps.maps (pid=2063, uid=10039) is not exported from uid 10023 due to receiver com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.reporting.service.ExternalChangeReceiver

I/ActivityManager(  506): Start proc com.google.android.apps.maps:FriendService for broadcast com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.googlenav.friend.android.ServiceReceiver: pid=2088 uid=10039 gids={50039, 3003, 1015, 1028}

D/dalvikvm( 2063): GC_CONCURRENT freed 770K, 9% free 9126K/9936K, paused 2ms+12ms, total 39ms

I/dalvikvm( 2063): Total arena pages for JIT: 11

I/dalvikvm( 2063): Total arena pages for JIT: 12

I/dalvikvm( 2063): Total arena pages for JIT: 13

I/dalvikvm( 2063): Total arena pages for JIT: 14

I/dalvikvm( 2063): Total arena pages for JIT: 15

I/dalvikvm( 2063): Total arena pages for JIT: 16

I/dalvikvm( 2063): Total arena pages for JIT: 17

I/ActivityManager(  506): Start proc com.google.android.apps.maps:LocationFriendService for broadcast com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.googlenav.friend.reporting.LocationReportingIntentReceiver: pid=2100 uid=10039 gids={50039, 3003, 1015, 1028}

I/dalvikvm( 2063): Total arena pages for JIT: 18

D/dalvikvm( 2100): GC_CONCURRENT freed 317K, 4% free 8778K/9124K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 18ms

I/ActivityManager(  506): No longer want com.facebook.orca (pid 26305): empty #17

D/dalvikvm( 2063): GC_CONCURRENT freed 321K, 8% free 9236K/9936K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 17ms

D/dalvikvm( 2063): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 251K, 7% free 9265K/9936K, paused 23ms, total 23ms

W/Settings( 2063): Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.

D/dalvikvm( 2063): GC_CONCURRENT freed 520K, 7% free 9256K/9936K, paused 5ms+5ms, total 42ms

D/dalvikvm( 2063): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 30ms

D/ALSAStreamOps(  162): setParameters(): keyRouting with device 0x2

D/ALSAModule(  162): s_route: devices 0x2 in mode 0

D/ALSAModule(  162): switchDevice: device 2 mode:0

D/ALSAModule(  162): s_is_tmus: mnc_mcc :  310260

D/ALSAModule(  162): s_is_tmus: mnc_mcc :  310260

D/ALSAModule(  162): No valid input device: 0

D/ALSAModule(  162): switchDevice,rxDev:Speaker, txDev:(null), curRxDev:Speaker, curTxDev:DMIC Endfire TMUS

D/alsa_ucm(  162): snd_use_case_set(): uc_mgr 0x417b5d58 identifier _enadev value Speaker

D/ALSAModule(  162): switchDevice: curTxUCMDevivce DMIC Endfire TMUS curRxDevDevice Speaker

D/AudioStreamOutALSA(  162): mHandle->useCase: HiFi Lowlatency

D/ALSAModule(  162): s_route: devices 0x2 in mode 0

D/ALSAModule(  162): switchDevice: device 2 mode:0

D/ALSAModule(  162): s_is_tmus: mnc_mcc :  310260

D/ALSAModule(  162): s_is_tmus: mnc_mcc :  310260

D/ALSAModule(  162): No valid input device: 0

D/ALSAModule(  162): switchDevice,rxDev:Speaker, txDev:(null), curRxDev:Speaker, curTxDev:DMIC Endfire TMUS

D/alsa_ucm(  162): snd_use_case_set(): uc_mgr 0x417b5d58 identifier _enadev value Speaker

D/ALSAModule(  162): switchDevice: curTxUCMDevivce DMIC Endfire TMUS curRxDevDevice Speaker

D/alsa_ucm(  162): snd_use_case_set(): uc_mgr 0x417b5d58 identifier _verb value HiFi Lowlatency

D/alsa_ucm(  162): Set mixer controls for Speaker enable 1

D/ACDB-LOADER(  162): ACDB -> send_afe_cal

D/alsa_ucm(  162): Set mixer controls for HiFi Lowlatency enable 1

D/ALSAModule(  162): Device value returned is hw:0,14

D/ALSAModule(  162): setHardwareParams: reqBuffSize 1024 channels 2 sampleRate 48000

D/ALSAModule(  162): setHardwareParams: buffer_size 2048, period_size 1024, period_cnt 2

D/ALSAStreamOps(  162): setParameters(): keyRouting with device 0x2

D/ALSAModule(  162): s_route: devices 0x2 in mode 0

D/ALSAModule(  162): switchDevice: device 2 mode:0

D/ALSAModule(  162): s_is_tmus: mnc_mcc :  310260

D/ALSAModule(  162): s_is_tmus: mnc_mcc :  310260

D/ALSAModule(  162): No valid input device: 0

D/ALSAModule(  162): switchDevice,rxDev:Speaker, txDev:(null), curRxDev:Speaker, curTxDev:DMIC Endfire TMUS

D/alsa_ucm(  162): snd_use_case_set(): uc_mgr 0x417b5d58 identifier _enadev value Speaker

D/alsa_ucm(  162): Set mixer controls for HiFi Lowlatency enable 1

D/ALSAModule(  162): switchDevice: curTxUCMDevivce DMIC Endfire TMUS curRxDevDevice Speaker

D/dalvikvm(25785): GC_CONCURRENT freed 417K, 11% free 9287K/10340K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 23ms

E/GameAgent( 4789): Unable to retrieve 1P application 191479565208 from network

W/dqi     ( 4789): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {bearer=WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token}

E/Volley  ( 4789): [494] il.a: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me

W/dqi     ( 4789): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {bearer=WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token}

E/Volley  ( 4789): [494] il.a: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me

W/dqi     ( 4789): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {bearer=WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token}

E/Volley  ( 4789): [495] il.a: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me

W/dqi     ( 4789): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {bearer=WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token}

E/Volley  ( 4789): [495] il.a: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me

E/SignInIntentService( 4789): There is no linked app associated with this client ID.

E/SignInIntentService( 4789): aol

E/SignInIntentService( 4789):      at ajy.a(SourceFile:108)

E/SignInIntentService( 4789):      at abm.a(SourceFile:213)

E/SignInIntentService( 4789):      at abm.a(SourceFile:194)

E/SignInIntentService( 4789):      at aav.a(SourceFile:486)

E/SignInIntentService( 4789):      at aqu.a(SourceFile:221)

E/SignInIntentService( 4789):      at com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesSignInIntentService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:343)

E/SignInIntentService( 4789):      at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)

E/SignInIntentService( 4789):      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

E/SignInIntentService( 4789):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

E/SignInIntentService( 4789):      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

E/LoadSelfFragment( 1244): Unable to sign in - application does not have a registered client ID

I/Prime31-Proxy(26004): onActivityResult called. finishing activity

D/Prime31 (26004): onActivityResult, req 9001 response 10004

D/Prime31 (26004): responseCode != RESULT_OK, so not reconnecting.

D/Prime31 (26004): giveUp: giving up on connection. Status code: 4

I/Prime31-GPSUtil(26004): b() No error string provided for errorCode: 4

I/Prime31-GPSUtil(26004): a() No error string provided for errorCode: 4
```

Answer (score 2):

This was driving me nuts for a while. This worked for me:

1. Log into the Developer Console
2. Click on Game Services, then Testing
3. Delete the tester account that's not working.
4. Re-add the tester account.

Worked right away after I did this. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use only your phone's main account for testing.

However I'm not sure if this limitation is in effect only [for in-app purchases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045686/how-do-i-change-which-test-account-to-use-on-android-in-app-billing), or for anything that involves google play.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

You need to generate a signed app then run on your real device.

Make sure you include app ID in your manifest file:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

You can get the app_id in linked app here:
[image]